# How to check if rows exist PDO PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm learning PHP PDO and I need some help with codes. I have 2 Questions today.

**First Question:**
How can I check if row exist in table with **Network_Code** and **Niche**, if there is column with same ID to proceed, but with same ID and Niche to die message.

```
    $network_code = $_GET[ 'ID' ];
    $Niche      = $_GET[ 'Niche' ];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `affiliates` (ID, Niche, Language, lockerURL, Network_Code, Google_ID) VALUES (NULL, '$Niche', '$Language', '$domain', '$network_code ', '$Google_ID')";

    $query = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
    $query->execute();
```

**Second Question:** 
Is there any other way that I can use: **$system_default[ 0 ]->column** because I think that is wrong way, so I need something like this: **$system_default->column**
    class default_system {

```
    function __construct( $pdo ) {

        $this->pdo = $pdo;

    }

    function getData() {

        $ID     = $_GET[ 'id' ];

        $Niche  = "clash-clans";

        $query = $this->pdo->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `affiliates` WHERE `Network_Code` = '$ID' AND `Niche` = '$Niche'" ); 
        $query->execute();  

        return $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ); // Return an Array of objects

    }

}   

$db_system = new default_system( $pdo );
$system_default = $db_system->getData();

echo $system_default[ 0 ]->lockerURL;
```

Comment: If you're already preparing the queries, use parameter binding instead of interpolating arbitrary $_GET input.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Can you give example? I updated question...

Comment: Why don't you look for your examples in the PHP manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example for First Question, you can try to solve your problem certain ways below is example of it. you can read more about pdo from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

```
$query=$dbh->prepare("SELECT secret FROM users WHERE username=:param");
$query->bindParam(':param', $param);
$query->execute();
$result = $query -> fetch();
print_r($result);
```

**For second issue**

```
echo $system_default['lockerURL'];
```

and remove `echo $system_default[ 0 ]->lockerURL;` line

Comment: What to put in bindParam?

Comment: Its your variable  $Niche

Comment: I can't put in comment, this is what I used: https://pastebin.com/EsRRFziu   and I call it like this: $system_default->lockerURL ...... don't work

Comment: right what happen

Comment: @vBulletin try print_r($system_default ) remove ->locker

Comment: Here is full code: https://pastebin.com/wFyZjavp I got Error:  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in get_data.module.php on line 40